# Got a Warning For Enabling Firmware TPM

Tags: hard-drive, bios, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I recently enabled Firmware TPM in my BIOS in order to see if my system is compatible with Windows 11.

My question is about the following warning I got when I enabled Firmware TPM:

> Intel PTT is a hardware TPM 2.0 implementation integrated in Intel
> ME/CSME/TXE for credential storage and key management. The firmware
> TPM key will be stored in Intel ME data region once you enable Intel
> PTT and Windows BitLocker for drive encryption. Please note that when
> the recovery key is lost or when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced, the
> system will not boot into the operating system and the data will stay
> encrypted and cannot be restored.

Below are my questions:

1. Since I never want to enable BitLocker and I only enabled TPM so I can upgrade to Windows 11 in the future, is this warning safe to ignore for my case?
2. *"The firmware TPM key will be stored in Intel ME data region once you enable Intel PTT and Windows BitLocker for drive encryption."*

   Where is this "Intel ME data region" going to be located? It doesn't sound like something that I can get to using Windows Explorer.

   Also, what is the "firmware TPM key" used for?
3. *"Please note that when the recovery key is lost or when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced, the system will not boot into the operating system and the data will stay encrypted and cannot be restored."*

   Regarding "when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced," does this mean that users who turn on BitLocker should first turn it off before they replace their BIOS ROM chips?

   If so, what happens if they make the mistake of replacing their BIOS ROM chip before turning off BitLocker? Can they just put the old BIOS ROM chip back and turn BitLocker off, or did they just permanently encrypt their system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, as the quoted text mentions, note that the same system volume can have *multiple* decryption keys added. In addition to a TPM-protected key, the system volume will usually have a numeric [recovery key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-10-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6).

As long as you have the recovery key written down, you can *always* use it to unlock the volume – even if the TPM has been changed or refuses to do the job, or even if you're accessing it through Linux, or even if the disk is moved to a different computer entirely.

(If you have Windows Pro and use the full version of BitLocker (as opposed to the reduced "Device Encryption" feature that Windows Home has), you might have seen that it also supports USB-stored key files and even ordinary passwords. Each of those "protectors" is completely independent from the rest, and only the ones which actually mention "TPM" in their name depend on a TPM – the rest will continue to work without.)

> Since I never want to enable BitLocker and I only enabled TPM so I can upgrade to Windows 11 in the future, is this warning safe to ignore for my case?

Yes – if you're sure that BitLocker hasn't been *automatically* enabled, either.

(If you didn't have the TPM before, then most likely it hasn't, as the automatic "Device Encryption" feature requires a TPM – but it never hurts to double-check, e.g. using `manage-bde -status c:`.)

Note that the TPM can be used for other purposes besides BitLocker, so clearing its data might disconnect the computer from Azure AD or Windows Hello for Business, or lose license activations in some third-party apps. But if you didn't have the TPM enabled before, then you're not using any of those features anyway.

> Where is this "Intel ME data region" going to be located? It doesn't sound like something that I can get to using Windows Explorer.

It's a flash memory area inside your CPU. The OS has no direct access to it at all (much like it wouldn't have direct access to a real TPM's memory, or indeed even to the NVRAM that stores your firmware settings).

> Also, what is the "firmware TPM key" used for?

It's the "root" encryption key that protects all other data managed by the TPM.

Other data, such as your BitLocker keys, is not stored *in* the TPM itself – it has only a very small amount of secure flash memory, just enough for 3–4 cryptographic keys. Everything else is returned back to the OS, just encrypted using the "root" key, such that only the TPM itself can decrypt it. (So the BitLocker TPM protector is really stored on the disk itself.)

This gives the illusion of the TPM having practically infinite storage (by having the OS automatically swap things in and out of the TPM's RAM), while also allowing that storage to be instantly "cleared" (by destroying the root key).

> Regarding "when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced," does this mean that users who turn on BitLocker should first turn it off before they replace their BIOS ROM chips?

Yes, or they should *suspend* BitLocker – instead of decrypting all data, this just stores the master decryption key right on the disk, without any protection. (When BitLocker is "resumed", it wipes that key.) Suspending the encryption in this way is very fast, while fully disabling BitLocker and decrypting a terabyte-sized disk can take many hours.

However, they *also* should have the recovery key written down. Ignore the mistaken "or" that's in your quote – knowing the recovery key makes you completely independent from the TPM or any other system hardware.

> If so, what happens if they make the mistake of replacing their BIOS ROM chip before turning off BitLocker? Can they just put the old BIOS ROM chip back and turn BitLocker off, or did they just permanently encrypt their system?

Not sure, because there are really two things in play: the root encryption key that's used by fTPM, and the system state measurement that is done with all TPMs.

First, even with a discrete TPM, the "sealing" process used by Windows deliberately binds the BitLocker key to certain bits of the system state. For example, booting from a USB stick or disabling Secure Boot will make the TPM refuse to unseal the key because the system state has changed. But this doesn't destroy anything, and returning to original settings will allow the key to be unsealed again.

However, with an fTPM, it's the firmware that actually holds the actual root encryption key that's used for sealing. It's most likely to be in the CPU, not in the "BIOS ROM", but it is *possible* that changing things around may cause the firmware to completely reset the fTPM, making all previously sealed data irrecoverable.

Comment: Nicely explained. However, as it seems to be that the slightest hiccup or user error will forever lose your data, I wouldn't go near any of this without *first* having a known-good backup. We already get 10 questions a day which wouldn't exist if the user already had a backup. I can see this making it worse.

Comment: @Tetsujin - The author can enable BitLocker and NOT use the TPM to store the BitLocker key.  While I agree the requirement is concerning, Microsoft if what I am hearing is true, will backup the recovery key automatically to the users Microsoft account (hence the reason a Microsoft Account is required).  Which I don’t see any difference between an Apple, Google, or Samsung account

Comment: It's possible that the TPM requirement will only be applicable to OEMs. Similarly, the CPU requirement list may not yet be complete.

Comment: You say "As long as you have the recovery key written down, you can always use it to unlock the volume", but the warning said "when the recovery key is lost *or* when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced", not "when the recovery key is lost *and* when the BIOS ROM chip is replaced". If you're saying the warning is wrong, can you make that clear?

Comment: "or even if the disk is moved to a different computer entirely." Does this also include systems that don't have any kind of TPM? Would I be able to connect a harddrive to, for example, a raspberry pi using a USB dock and then use the key to unlock it?

Comment: @MMM: Yes. BitLocker works pretty much exactly like Linux LUKS with multiple keyslots does – the TPM only protects one of the "passwords", but isn't involved anywhere else in the process; it's all just regular software crypto. So as long as you have another one of the keyslot passwords (such as the recovery key) you can use libbde or dislocker or even cryptsetup to access the volume. (And as far as TPMs go, their entire value is being able to seal data to _one specific_ TPM, or to one specific system state. They don't provide much in terms of generic "any TPM" features.)